# C++ preprocessor: test if class exists

Tags: c++, class, eigen, preprocessor

**Is it possible for the C++ preprocessor to test if a class exists? If so, how would I do this?**

I am writing C++ code that uses an Eigen class (CompleteOrthogonalDecomposition) that is only in the newer version of Eigen. The code that I am currently using just checks the version:

```
#if EIGEN_VERSION_AT_LEAST(3,3,4) 
// code for new version of eigen here
#else 
// fall-back code for old version of eigen
#endif
```

I would be able to check if the specific class that I need exists. The following does not compile but it shows what I would like to do:

```
#if CLASS_EXISTS(CompleteOrthogonalDecomposition)  // does not compile
// code for new version of eigen here
#else 
// fall-back code for old version of eigen
#endif
```

Comment: When the preprocessor is running, _no class exists_.  A "class" is a property of the C++ language.  The preprocessor processes **before** any code is compiled.

Comment: You can use template for that not macro

Comment: Indeed.  Templates would solve the described problem handily.